# How do I match old-style (Blender Internal) specular hardness with new-style (Cycles) Principled BSDF Roughness?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to match the specularity size of an old Internal material (controlled by a Hardness value) and a new Cycles material (controlled by a Roughness value).

[image: comparison of Cycles and Internal specularity sizes]

As can be seen in the image, Internal Hardness is not nearly as linear as Cycles Roughness is. But I can't find out what sort of math to do to the hardness to make it match the roughness - the Blender source code from the 2.79 era is unsearchable because it's historical, and I can't find any other hints as to what the "Hardness" value logically represents that aren't dead links.

Notes:

- I'm not going for perfect accuracy. I just need the average person to look at the two rows here and think "yeah the shiny part looks the same size".
- The roughness numbers in the image are backwards because I'm actually working with gloss (the opposite).
- The max hardness in the image is 130 because [that's what the Hardness texture input does at 1.0 power](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/introduction.html). I used the default CookTorr, but if one of the others is easier to work with or more accurate for this, that's fine.

Comment: With what shader (Blinn, Phong, Cook-Torrence)? My guess is the 2.79 source code is [this](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v2.79-release/source/blender/render/intern/source/shadeoutput.c#L588-L684), which makes it look like Hardness corresponds to Phong shininess. Maybe see if [this](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-converting-shininess-to-roughness-and-vice-versa) helps.

Comment: I mentioned using CookTorr in the notes, but that using something else is fine if the results turn out easier or better. That code looks weird because (if I understand it correctly) it seems to imply that hardness only takes effect in blocks of 2^n, I'll have to experiment with it. I'd seen that other question before but it's very generic and was hoping for a more Blender-specific answer.

Comment: If you mean spec(inp, hard), it's just doing inp^hard plus some clamping using unrolled exponentiation by doubling. I think you'll still have to do swatch matching though.

Comment: Ah so it is, this explains a lot. I might be able to self-answer this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the code linked to in the comments](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v2.79-release/source/blender/render/intern/source/shadeoutput.c#L588-L684), Hardness is basically applied as an exponent to the specularity value. So I started to try some formulas and got `internal ~= 130*cycles^2`, or `cycles ~= sqrt(internal/130)`.

[image]

It's not all that close but it's a significant improvement - and because internal Hardness is locked to being an integer, I don't think it's possible to do any better on the rough end because no intermediate values exist.